# How can I encourage the adoption of Document IDs?

Tags: 2010, hyperlink, document-id

I am in the process of setting up a new Team Site, and I have already activated and configured the Document ID service on the site, and added the Document ID column to various library views and web parts. But since the Document ID column neither displays the filename nor offers the dropdown menu, I still have to include the `Name (linked to document with edit menu)` field in my views as well.
(Note that many of my coworkers have been at the company for a long time, and are more comfortable with shared drives, email attachments, and *shudders* Lotus Notes, than with SharePoint.)

While some users will be receptive to training, others are only interested in learning the minimum they need to know in order to be able to do their own work - they're never going to appreciate the nuances of *why* a Document ID link is better than an absolute URL, because for the question "Will clicking this link allow me to open/edit the document?" (which is all they really care about), the answer is yes in either case.

I want to set things up in such a way that the simplest and most obvious way to get a hyperlink will result in a Document ID link, and that getting an absolute URL requires at least a small amount of extra effort (one additional mouse click or hover-delay would satisfice).

An ideal solution is one that can be implemented through any combination of:

- the browser UI
- Calculated Columns
- custom views
- workflows

I have access to SharePoint Designer, and can also use CSS, JavaScript, and/or jQuery in a CEWP, but would prefer a no-code or minimal-code solution, for ease of maintenance and in case I transition my SP admin duties to someone else in the future. Also, I do not have access to PowerShell or Central Administration; I'm a Site Collection Administrator.